# Bayesian Biased Prior Formula

Tags: bayesian, prior, uninformative-prior, improper-prior

I know that for a Bayesian uniform/flat prior, the formula is 1/n (and n=1), as each value has an equal chance of being chosen.

However, is there an equation for when the prior is biased/informative? For example, so that the prior is skewed to the left or to the right?

Comment: uniform has nothing to do with uninformative

Comment: @NeilG when I say uniform I mean flat prior

Comment: Right, and that has nothing to do with being uninformative.

Comment: Suppose I give you a weighted coin with some unknown bias probability $0\le p\le 1$, then you might argue that the uninformative belief over $p$ is uniform over $[0,1]$.  Now, suppose you travel to another planet where the aliens like to measure biases in *odds* $0 \le o = \frac{p}{1+p}$.   Then, you might similarly argue that the uninformative belief over $o$ is flat on $[0, \infty)$.  But, these aren't the same distribution.  So which one is uninformative?

Comment: @Neil G: In a finite parameter set, the uniform can more easily be argued to be "non-informative" as the change-of-variable argument does not apply so naturally.

Comment: @Xi'an You're right.

Answer (score 3):

Yes, but just as there are many ways of a curve not being flat, there are many different non-flat priors. For example, a coin's bias could have a [$\operatorname{Beta}(α, β)$](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Beta_distribution) prior, which is only flat when $α$ and $β$ are both 1, or it could have a [triangular](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Triangular_distribution) prior with endpoints $0$ and $1$, which can't be flat no matter how you set the remaining parameter.